# How to pass parameter on next page by using setTimeout in ajax?

Tags: javascript, settimeout

I want to pass a value to the next page in `ajax` by using `setTimeout`.

actual code is

```
setTimeout(' window.location.href ="signin.php";',4000);
```

but I want to write it like

```
 setTimeout(' window.location.href ="signin.php?success";',4000);
```

by this it not working.

Comment: check your browser console for errors

Comment: working fine at my end

Comment: share your full code ..? in your code no `ajax` use  ?

Answer (score 2):

Use this code for the functionality.

```
setTimeout(function(){ 
       window.location = "signin.php?success=y";
    }, 
4000);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//we store out timerIdhere
var timeOutId = 0;
//we define our function and STORE it in a var
var ajaxFn = function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/echo/html/',
            success: function (response) {
                if (response == 'True') {//YAYA
                    clearTimeout(timeOutId);//stop the timeout
                } else {//Fail check?
                    timeOutId = setTimeout(ajaxFn, 10000);//set the timeout again
                    console.log("call");//check if this is running
                    //you should see this on jsfiddle
                    // since the response there is just an empty string
                }
            }
        });
}
ajaxFn();//we CALL the function we stored 
//or you wanna wait 10 secs before your first call? 
//use THIS line instead
timeOutId = setTimeout(ajaxFn, 10000);
```

OR you can

```
setTimeout(function(){ 
       window.location = "somepage.php?success=y";
       //send id with page
    }, 
1000);
```

By :: https://stackoverflow.com/users/368070/gideon

Answer (score 0):

you can pass parameter as below

```
setTimeout(function(){ 
    window.location = "signin.php?success=true";
}, 3000);
```

This will work!

Answer (score 0):

in `url` you have to pass parameter so you need `?parameter=value`

so after link add `?paramenter` and after parameter set its value `=value`

`setTimeout('window.location.href ="signin.php?val=success";',4000);`